# draw number of lines in openlayers

Tags: openlayers

I have total 6 points in my array & one center point shown bellow

```
    var a = new Array();
        a[0] = [13.90,52.90];
        a[1] = [14.90,52.90];
        a[2] = [12.90,52.90];
        a[3] = [13.11,51.90];
        a[4] = [12.67,49.34];
        a[5] = [11.45,50.567];
        var centerpoint = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(13.41,52.52);
```

I want to draw line between all array points & centerpoint (i.e. line between a[0] & centerpoint, line between a[1] & centerpoint, etc.).

I am not able to do this by any way.

Can any one suggest some way to do this

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to draw 6 lines? You can create linestring with OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString, which takes array of OpenLayers.Geometry.Point's as parameter. Bear in mind that you can't use [13.90,52.90] directly, you have to create Point object, as you did with centerpoint.

```
for (var i = 0, len = a.length; i < len; i++) {
    var lineGeom = new OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString([
        new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(a[i][0], a[i][1]),
        centerpoint
    ]);
    var lineFeat = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(lineGeom);
    vectorLayer.addFeatures([lineFeat]);
}
```